# What's the difference between the anti klepto protocol and anti exfil?

Tags: security, cryptography, terminology, hardware-wallet

What is the difference between the [anti-klepto](https://shiftcrypto.ch/blog/anti-klepto-explained-protection-against-leaking-private-keys/) protocol (also [here](https://github.com/ElementsProject/secp256k1-zkp/blob/ed69ea79b429beae4260917e08fe60317d38ee8d/include/secp256k1_ecdsa_s2c.h#L100-L155)) and [Anti-Exfil](https://medium.com/blockstream/anti-exfil-stopping-key-exfiltration-589f02facc2e)? Is it the same thing just with different names or are there differences? It seems they are both addressing the nonce covert channel attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it the same thing just with different names [...]?

Yes.

This became known as "anti-klepto" initially (full disclosure: I suggested this name). Later, a decision at Blockstream was made to refer to the project as "anti-exfil", for the simple reason that the word "[kleptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleptography)" is a very rare term that probably only cryptography experts have heard of (as opposed to "exfiltration", which is understandable to a wider audience).